# Protractor test that an element is empty

Tags: javascript, protractor

`<div id='messagesDiv'></div>`

I want to test that this `div` element is empty.

```
var messagesDiv = element(by.id('messagesDiv'));
expect(messagesDiv).to...
```

How would I achieve that?

Comment: Check for [`.getInnerHtml()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getInnerHtml) should do the trick

Comment: Please confirm what test framework you are using Jasmine, Mocha etc.. as the syntax might be different dependent on the framework.

Comment: test framework is Jasmine

Comment: Any answer actually answered your question?

Answer (score 6):

I think this:

```
expect(messagesDiv.getText()).toBe('');
```

should do the trick. More information [here](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getText).

Comment: If using Mocha you can use the following: `expect(messagesDiv.getText()).to.eventually.equal('')` using chai-as-promised (as getText() returns a promise)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
expect (messagesDiv.text).toBe('')
```

Answer (score 0):

`expect(messagesDiv.getText()).toMatch(/^\s*$/);` will handle spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc. that HTML treats as empty but really might not be in the raw HTML.